# log4j.properties (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I am using maven and log4j, but the app cannot load log4j.properties that is in "/" and "/WEB-INF/classes/" inside my WAR file.

In my Java code:

```
try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(new FileInputStream("log4j.properties"));
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

Do I need extra configuration in my pom.xml? (apart from the dependency)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it is for applying the log4j properties keep it in src/test/resources. It will get picked up automatically. For the logging inside the container your app is deployed I believe the container should be dictating the configuration like jboss's log4j.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
 InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this as well:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(getClass().getResource("/<path if any>/log4j.properties"));
```